# Set up Docker to Use a Filesystem Folder to store Databases, UBUNTU?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, docker, ubuntu, dropbox

I just started using Docker (CE), so I am a relative novice.

I installed on UBUNTU 18.04.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu  $(lsb_release -cs)  stable" 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
sudo docker run --name some-postgres -v "/home/parallels/Desktop/Orthanc Dropbox/OrthancConfigs/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

I then installed DBeaver on UBUNTU, and I am able to connect to postgres after running the image/container (I need to read more to understand the difference).  I wanted to configure it to use a local filesystem folder to store the database rather than have them non-persistent when I run the image.  There is probably an issue with having a "space" in the Orthanc Dropbox filename, but not sure that I can change that because I'm running their client and it does that automatically.  You can use symlinks with Dropbox, but the actual files to sync have to be in the Dropbox folder, not the symlinks.  It would be nice if they supported the opposite arrangement.

I see there are quite a few config options, especially when you use a .yaml config file.  Ideally, I'll want to start up the Postgres Docker when I boot the system and shut it down when I shut down the system so that the operation is relatively seamless, but I want the database files stored on the system file system or on a mounted file system folder, probably within the Dropbox folder itself because it automatically syncs everything in that folder with the Dropbox Cloud.

If I can get that to work, I'll also probably want to do the same for a LAMP stack (MySQL, Apache, PHP 7.4, also with the DB as above) and for an NGINX server.  It would actually even be nice to package NGINX, PHP-FPM & Postgres in my own custom container.

So the goal is:

1. Custom Docker container with Postgres, NGINX, PHP-FPM 7.4, with DB, web directories and config files on file system.
2. Custom Docker container with Apache, MySQL, PHP 7.4, with DB, web directories and config files on file system.

I can read the documentation a little further, but I presume this really isn't that difficult, and it seems like there should be some already made Docker images that do something pretty similar.

Another option is to use Docker images/containers for Postgres and MySQL with the database files on my file system, and then just install Apache, NGINX, PHP/PHP-FPM, on my system natively.  That way I can use Docker for the Databases and my system for the rest.

So:

1. Custom Docker container with Postgres, with DB on file system.
2. Custom Docker container with MySQL, with DB on file system.

I have some .sh scripts to make rolling backups of some database files, so I presume there would be a way to use those with the Docker images if I wanted to, although that might not be necessary with the backup in the Cloud.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases, whether MySQL or Postgres, have rather strict requirements on filesystems.

Its unlikely that an archival/sharing based Dropbox connector meets these requirements.

Multiple concurrent instantiates on the same storage there certainly won't be possible.

Recommend running locally and have the backup mechanism push their backups to your Dropbox based storage. That way you'll actually have a backup, in addition to a disaster recovery.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll probably dispense with Docker Images for now.  The way I have things setup is with a SSD for system disk and then a RAID for data.  I think I can put the "Data" in the Dropbox folder.  That gets written to dynamically by another app, but not DB's like MySQL and Postgres, and I can just run CRON script to dump rolling backups of the databases into the DropBox folder as well.  I think that will work for now.